# Find and delete a string in a vector of strings in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find a 2 part name in a vector of strings and I have what I thought would work and it doesn't. I can not use iterators. This is my code, it is part of a larger program, it's a single function in a program with 5 functions.

```
int deletenames()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    string strFileName;
    string strFName,strLName;
    vector<string> vecStudent;
    string strDFName, strDLName;
    int i=0;
    char line[80];
    //delets a name
    cout << endl<< " Enter a name to be deleted( First and Last Name):";
    cin>>strDFName>>strDLName;

    for(i<0;strDFName+ " "+strDLName=strFName+ " "+strLName; i++)
    {
        if(strDFName+ " "+strDLName=strFName+ " "+strLName)
            {
                vecStudent.erase;
                cout << "Student Deleted";
        }
    }

    // open output file for writing
    outFile.open(strFileName.c_str());
    if ( outFile.fail())
    {
        cout<<" Output file error! Student was not added"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //display the content of the vector
    for(int i=0; i<vecStudent.size(); i++)
        cout<< vecStudent[i]<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<vecStudent.size();i++)
        outFile<<vecStudent[i]<<endl;
    outFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

I get the following error messages from Microsoft Visual Studio That I'm using to compile it.

```
main.cpp
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(78): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(64): warning C4101: 'line' : unreferenced local variable
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(105): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(108): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(90): warning C4101: 'line' : unreferenced local variable
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(132): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(135): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(122): warning C4101: 'line' : unreferenced local variable
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(158): warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(158): error C2451: conditional expression of type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' is illegal
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(160): error C2451: conditional expression of type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' is illegal
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(162): error C3867: 'std::vector<_Ty>::erase': function call missing argument list; use '&std::vector<_Ty>::erase' to create a pointer to member
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(179): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\ace\desktop\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\cpsc 1103 assingment 4\main.cpp(182): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
```

Comment: What exactly is the loop termination condition of the first for loop?

Comment: "*I can not use iterators.*" Why on earth not?? Why can you use `std::vector<>` but not take advantage of the primary interface for said class? And what do you think `for(i<0;strDFName+ " "+strDLName=strFName+ " "+strLName; i++)` does?

Comment: "I can not use iterators" Well, you must.

Answer (score 0):

It seems certain that at least one (probably both) of the places you have for `(x; a=b; a++)`, or `if (a=b)`, you actually intended a comparison instead of an assignment (i.e., you intended to use `==` instead of `=`).

In particular, in both cases the left side is a temporary value built from concatenating some strings together. Generally speaking, assigning to a temporary is impossible. Even when it is possible, it's generally a mistake.

As an aside, you also seem to have duplicated the code to display the contents of the array (i.e., you have two copies of that code). Also, unless this is for an assignment where you have to do things "by hand", you probably want to use `std::find` instead of writing a loop to find the string.

Comment: It's for a 1st year programming assingment and the instructions said not to use iterators and that It was to be done using a for loop to do so. If you don't follow the prof's instructions exactly you fail the whole assingment.